# Springboot @Value not loading

Tags: spring-boot

In my sample Springboot project on [Github](https://github.com/Semo/npgen), the `@Value` property won't get loaded when starting the application. I cannot explain the strange behavior and hope that anyone could help me please to solve it and to avoid such stupid errors?

```java
@RestController
public class PostClient {

    @Value(value = "${target.uri}")
    public String uri;

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    public PostClient() {}

    public HttpStatus postNumberPlate(CamImage camImage) {

        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("numplate", camImage.getIdentifier());
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String,
                        Object>>(map, headers);

        ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(camImage.getData()) {
            @Override
            public String getFilename() {
                return camImage.getIdentifier() + ".png";
            }
        };
        map.add("image", resource);

        System.out.println(uri);

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity, String.class);

        return result.getStatusCode();
    }
}
```

The `application.properties`

```
target.uri=http://localhost:9001/postoffice
```

I [read](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) that the `@Value` is a core functionality of Springboot and should work fine. My project is so small, that I wonder what might broke the framework's behavior of automatic value replacement. I found different and similar questions regarding the `@Value` issue, but a real explanation cannot be found.

I tried to use a `@Component` Class with getters/setters and tried to `@Autowire` it into the shown Class, but that didn't work, too.

I'd like to go the proposed way of the Springboot reference, because any hard-coded String will result in problems, when building docker containers, where I must pass a configuration parameter. So I cannot only rely on a fixed `application.properties` in the classpath.

EDIT:
Running the application looks like:

```java
shell:>one
Euro Plate                                      # unimportant sysout
CamImage [identifier=BNAYG63, data=[B@4f4c4c4b] # generated plate
null                   # from sysout here should be the address!!
URI is not absolute
Details of the error have been omitted. You can use the stacktrace command to print the full stacktrace.

shell:>stacktrace
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.base/java.net.URL.fromURI(URL.java:674)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:579)
    at dev.semo.npgen.service.PostClient.postNumberPlate(PostClient.java:45)
    at dev.semo.npgen.shell.NumberplateClientCommands.one(NumberplateClientCommands.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.shell.Shell.evaluate(Shell.java:180)
    at org.springframework.shell.Shell.run(Shell.java:142)
    at org.springframework.shell.jline.InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.run(InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
    at dev.semo.npgen.NpgenApplication.main(NpgenApplication.java:10)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

Comment: Just use like following `@Value("${target.uri}")    private String uri;`

Comment: Thx. But what is the difference? I tried, but same problem.

Comment: Above comment is not the correct one. You have to autowire the `PostClient' instead of creating an object. Please refer the answer below.

Comment: The `PostClient` you are using isn't managed by Spring. You are doing `new PostClient()` to construct an instance, instead you should `@Autowire` the `PostClient`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thx for your efforts.:-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pulled your source from github and tested. Initially it was throwing error as you mentioned. After I have changed like below it is working fine. You should to autowire the `PostClient`, because the scanning happened and loaded the defaults while you started the application.

```
@ShellComponent
public class NumberplateClientCommands {

    @Autowired
    private PostClient postClient;

    .....

    @ShellMethod("Sends one simple POST request.")
    public String one() throws FileNotFoundException {
        NumberPlateUtility np = new NumberPlateUtility();
        HttpStatus response = postClient.postNumberPlate(np.completeImage());
        if (response == HttpStatus.ACCEPTED) {
            return "Request sent successfully.";
        }
        return String.format("Request failed: %s", response.getReasonPhrase());
    }

   .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Follow this Code Snip

```
@Value("${target.uri}")
private String uri;
```

Comment: Thank you, but in a comment from Chokkan above there is no difference. I already used this syntax and it did not work.